# Prove that the $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)=0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $g(x,y)=\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{|x|+|y|}$. How would I prove that the $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)=0$?

I was looking through my textbook and found that for all real numbers $s$ and $t$, $|\sin(s+t)|\le |s+t|\le |s|+|t|$ Then you squeeze. Does this apply here and how do I use that to prove the above?

Comment: Right, so $\sin^2(x-y) \le (x-y)^2.$ Play around with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find $ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin^2 (x-y)}{|x|+|y|} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988523/how-to-find-lim-x-y-to0-0-frac-sin2-x-yxy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you know, $|\sin (x-y)| \leq |x-y| \leq |x| + |-y| = |x|+|y|$, so that

$$ g(x,y) = \frac{\sin^2 (x-y)}{|x|+|y|} \leq \frac{(|x|+|y|)^2}{|x|+|y|} = |x|+|y|$$

What happens as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ to this upper bound? What is a lower bound to this expression (hint: that's deceptively easy).

CONTINUATION:

Through the work above we have found an upper bound for the function $g(x,y)$. We see that as this upper bound ($|x|+|y|$) approaches $(0,0)$, we get $0$. Now notice that $g(x,y)$ is always positive, so it has a lower bound of $0$. Since this lower bound approaches $0$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$, we have that the lower and upper bounds of $g(x,y)$ are equal at this limit, so the function must be equal to that value as well (this is according to the squeeze theorem and the fact that all these functions are continuous). Therefore, the limit is 0.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding

Comment: I'll post more details. Do you understand what I've written so far?

Comment: Yeah I got that much

Answer (score 1):

An idea:

$$\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{|x|+|y|}=\sin(x-y)\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}\frac{x-y}{|x|+|y|}$$

Now observe that

$$\begin{align}&\sin(x-y)\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0\\{}\\&\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}1\\{}\\&\left|\frac{x-y}{|x|+|y|}\right|\le\frac{|x|+|y|}{|x|+|y|}=1\end{align}$$

Thus we're done...

Comment: Sorry, but how does this prove that the limit is 0?

Comment: Something that goes to zero times something that converges to one times something **bounded** forces *all* to tend to zero, of course...